# check if array contain object with field == x

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array:

```
"users" : [
        {
          "user_id" : 7,
          "username" : "kfc"
        },
        {
          "user_id" : 2,
          "username" : "mac"
        },
        {
          "user_id" : 56,
          "username" : "king"
        }
      ]
```

I want to check if a user with id 7 exist for example

I tried to script this:

```
"user_exist":{
  "script":{
    "source": "params?._source?.likes.contains({user_id=7})"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're using `script`s for such simple queries. Try this one

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "users.user_id": {
        "value": 7
      }
    }
  }
}
```